# Server-side DataTable Sorting in RichFaces

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces

I have a data table with a variable number of columns and a data scroller. How can I enable server side sorting? I prefer that it be fired by the user clicking the column header.

```
<rich:datascroller for="instanceList" actionListener="#{pageDataModel.pageChange}"/>
<rich:dataTable id="instanceList" rows="10" value="#{pageDataModel}"
                var="fieldValues" rowKeyVar="rowKey">
  <rich:columns value="#{pageDataModel.columnNames}" var="column" index="idx">
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="#{column}"/>
    </f:facet>          
    <h:outputText value="#{classFieldValues[idx]}" />
  </rich:columns>
</rich:dataTable>
```

I already have a method on the bean for executing the sort.

```
public void sort(int column)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up doing it manually. I adding a support tag to the header text tag, like so.

```
<h:outputText value="#{column}">
  <a4j:support event="onclick" action="#{pageDataModel.sort(idx)}"
               eventsQueue="instancesQueue"
               reRender="instanceList,instanceListScroller"/>
</h:outputText>
```

To get the ascending/descending arrows, I added a css class.

```
<h:outputText value="#{column}" styleClass="#{pageDataModel.getOrderClass(idx)}" >
  <a4j:support event="onclick" action="#{pageDataModel.sort(idx)}"
               eventsQueue="instancesQueue"
               reRender="instanceList,instanceListScroller"/>
</h:outputText>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a fairly elegant solution to this solution here:

http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/sortingFeature.jsf?tab=ex-usage

This demo avoids using the  tag.

Comment: This shows how to do external sorting, but the sorting is still happening on the client side.  I believe that OP is interested in catching the click event from clicking the headers and then having the underlying datasource sorted on the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the "sortBy" property of "rich:columns", maybe that's what you're looking for.
[Richfaces Reference](http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossrichfaces/freezone/docs/devguide/en/html_single/index.html#columns)

Comment: I cannot get this attribute to work consistently. Anyway he said server side sorting.  Isn't rich:columns with sortBy client side sorting?

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just use Collection.sort() when you retrieve the List?

Answer (score 1):

Your datamodel needs to implement "Modifiable" interface.

The datatable will call it's `modify()` method to do serverside 
sorting and filtering.